# What is the difference between JS "execution time" and "tool run time"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

I'm trying to make sense of this chart to help pick the best transpiling technique for ES6 to ES5 but I'm not sure what the difference is in "execution time" and "tool run time".

https://github.com/samccone/The-cost-of-transpiling-es2015-in-2016#raw-data

Answer (score 1):

In that post, the author analyses the use of pre-processing tools like Babel, TypeScript and Webpack, the *tool run time* he refers to, is how long these tools take to process the files.

On the other hand, the *execution* and *compile times* he refers to is how long the engine takes to compile and execute the processed JavaScript files.

---

> Tool run time (gathered by `time make <tool>`)
>   *js execution time on page load (gathered by `big-rig`)
>   *js compile time (gathered by `big-rig`)

While both `time` and `big-rig` are CLIs,  `time` is for CLI run time, and `big-rig` is specifically for JavaScript files, boasting the ability to display information on different parts of the load:

[image: big-rig]

Photo from [their repo](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/node-big-rig/)

Comment: So tool time is how long it takes for Babel (etc.) to convert ES6 to ES5; and execution time is how long it takes to execute certain (all?) functions in the script. But if tool time is how long it takes to process, then what is compile time? So many things to think about, what matters and what doesn't to the end user?

Comment: The engine has to compile the code before it can execute

Comment: It only has to compile once though right? Not every time a user loads a new page with the same JS on it?

Comment: Right, but does it have to do it every single time the page loads or is it usually cached after the initial compile?

Comment: No, JavaScript isn't cached in the browser, only static files like HTML and CSS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102771/discussion-between-corysimmons-and-quill).